# Integrate Google Calendar or Similar plugin in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-calendar-api

I have researched but didn't found any suitable link.. I want each Google Calendar's functionality to be available in my app either via Google calendar or any third party AngularJS library. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the API clients for Javascript and plug it into your angularJs application easily, https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/downloads
Basicly what you need to do is call the API using you API keys, you can do that with a simple `$http.{post|get}()` method.